# argparse argument may be str or int and the simplest way to handle it

Tags: python, argparse

I didn't know quite how to word the title but I'm trying to enter two variables with argparse. The first argument may be a string or an integer and the second argument will always be an integer.

The first example would be `python calnum.py -x 2 -y 4`. In my sample code below it sees the first argument as a string and not an int. I didn't specify `type=int` because of the second valid example below.

The other example would be `python calnum.py -x curve -y 0`.

If the first argument is curve then the 2nd argument should be 0. Below I set it to zero which works or is it better practice to display an error and have the user actually enter 0 for the second argument if they didn't enter zero or use the help command?

Actually if it's set to curve then y doesn't need to be entered at all and just set y = 0 but if a user enters something should I do something with it or ignore it and set it to 0 like in the code below or go about it another way entirely.

Also what is the best way to handle the first argument in regards to being an int. First verify if it's an int and then convert it to an int to do calculations? I have some code below and don't quite know what to do with it. I might be going about it all wrong possibly as I just started reading about argparse.

Is there any easy (short) way to handle those two examples from the command line? I prefer the easy to read code vs. short and complex as my experience is limited. Hopefully I explained that well enough and any help would be greatly appreciated or just ask if I missed explaining something, thank you.

```
import argparse

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

my_parser.add_argument('-x', action='store')
my_parser.add_argument('-y', action='store', type=int)

args = my_parser.parse_args()

if args.x == "curve":
    args.y = 0
elif str.isdigit(args.x):
    args.x = int(args.x)
```

Comment: To add a little more information. If I try and convert curve to an int it crashes the script vs. being handled as an exception. I don't know how to check if the str in the first argument is curve or "integer capable" and if it is "integer capable" then convert it to an integer for calculations if that makes sense.

Comment: `type='int' means, run `int(astring)` on the '-y' argument.  It converts the string, or raises an error.  Testing after parsing as you do with `x` is certainly an option.  There's no special benefit to doing all the testing/conversion within `argparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to handle it is to read it as a string, and use the function `str.isdecimal` to check if it's a number. If it is, you're safe to cast to int using `int(val)`, otherwise, treat it as a string.

Maybe like this:

```
import argparse

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

my_parser.add_argument('-x', action='store')
my_parser.add_argument('-y', action='store', type=int)

args = my_parser.parse_args()

if args.x.isdecimal():
    as_int = int(args.x)
else:
    args.y = 0
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was wondering one thing, if possible. If I set default values for x and y (both decimal values 2 and 4 for testing) and run the script without any arguments I see this error. ```if args.x.isdecimal(): AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'```. Is it possible to set just defaults and run the script with no arguments and not get an error? The default value of x is correct when I print it (before the if statement) but if I don't actually use the x argument it crashes on the if statement. y has no issue when run without the argument using default=4.

Comment: that is happening because the default values are integers, and when you let the defaults be used, `isdecimal()` fails because there is no such method for the `int` object (ie. `int.isdecimal()` does not exist). The quick way to fix that is to just put the default values in quotes (`my_parser.add_argument('-x', action='store', default="2")` which will force `x` to be a sting.

Comment: Basically I am forced to use ```-x``` argument at all times. If I don't use that argument then the script crashes with the error above. I set one required argument and the rest optional but I always have to use ```-x``` regardless.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I am going to accept this answer. I do like the other answer and it seems a bit more verbose but it keeps failing to work. Your answer is simple, I understand it and works and for me. I think that is what I need right now to help with learning. Thank you for the explanations also. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `type` argument of `add_argument` accept a callable that check and convert.

```
import argparse


def maybe_str_or_int(arg):
    try:
        return int(arg)  # try convert to int
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if arg == "curve":
        return arg
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("x must be an int or 'curve'")


my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

my_parser.add_argument('-x', action='store', type=maybe_str_or_int)
my_parser.add_argument('-y', action='store', type=int)

args = my_parser.parse_args(['-x', 'na'])  # cause error message
# args = my_parser.parse_args(['-x', 'curve'])  # no error
# args = my_parser.parse_args(['-x', '123'])  # no error

if args.x == "curve":
    args.y = 0
elif not isinstance(args.x, int):
    print(args.x)
```

Comment: I tried a ```-x 2``` and ```-x curve``` and ```-x na``` but none of them would display the ValueError "x must be an int or 'curve'". Shouldn't ```-x na``` display the message since it's not an int and it's not the str 'curve'?

Comment: @Arnie I updated the answer to use ArgumentError on Python 3.7. The message should be shown now.

Comment: I tried the same test with the revised code but it still isn't working. I see this error only when I run the script with ```-x na```.  ```error: argument -x: invalid maybe_str_or_int value: 'na'```. I am using Python 3.8.3 if that helps.

Comment: @Arnie I thought `ArgumentError` and `ArgumentTypeError` were the same but they aren't. Now the code (use `ArgumentTypeError`) showed `test2.py: error: argument -x: x must be an int or 'curve'` indeed. as mentioned in https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/argparse.html?highlight=argumenttypeerror#type